# How to get user_id in Open Cart 3?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I'm developing in admin side. And I needs to find user_id. The code

```
$this->user->getId()
```

provides no information. Is there any way to get user id.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best way:

```
You cannot directly access user_id from database since it is protected.
```

So you have to access it from session.

```
$this->session->data['user_id'];
```

This returns the id of currently logged user.